# Only want to use the return value and ignore the alert

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a function which will use multiple functions of which is pasted below. I want to ignore the alert and just use the return value, is this possible?
Thanks

```
function ageFormatAll()
{
   var age = document.getElementById('ageGrade').value;
   var patt=/^(?:\d{2}\.\d{2}|)$/;
   if (! patt.test(age) )
   {
    alert("Value entered doesn't match the correct format");
    return "Age grade doesn't match format.\n";
   } else 
   { return "" };
}
```

Comment: Did you think of deleting the line that does the `alert`?

Comment: Can you modify this function?

Comment: I wanted to try and use this function twice. Once for an onblur event to show the alert. Then using it again for an onclick event but I wouldn't want the alert for this, just the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Well officially you cannot. Just remove the alert from the function.

But there is a garbage and unreliable way to achieve what you want:

```
// remember alert to restore later
var alert_ = alert;

// override alert with an empty function
alert = function() {};

// get the result
var result = ageFormatAll();

// restore the alert function
alert = alert_;
```

But don't use this way: this is a nice thing to know but not to use.

Comment: monkey patching is neither "garbage" nor "unreliable".  Sometimes it's the only thing you have.   There are better ways of writing this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the alert? Or if you want to conditionally show the alert, modify the function. Put an if check as a parameter. This way, you can re use it in other scenarios as it is, and just pass a parameter when you do not want the alert.

```
function ageFormatAll(doNotShowAlert)
{
   var age = document.getElementById('ageGrade').value;
   var patt=/^(?:\d{2}\.\d{2}|)$/;
   if (! patt.test(age) )
   {
    if(doNotShowAlert !== undefined && doNotShowAlert) {
    alert("Value entered doesn't match the correct format");
    }
    return "Age grade doesn't match format.\n";
   } else 
   { return "" };
}
```